# Find the dimension of the vector space of 7×7 matrices with zero trace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

This was on a practice problem in a textbook I decided to take a look at and haven't been able to solve it. Any help?

Comment: what are you asking about this vector space?

Comment: To find the dimensions of it. Forgive me for not putting that into the question description.

Comment: Please edit you question

Comment: Think about the size of a basis that would span the space of $n \times n$ matrices with trace zero.

Comment: You have 49 variables (the entries of the matrix), and they need to satisfy one linear constraint.  One possible way to handle this is to recognize the space you want as the kernel of a map....

Comment: If $M$ is the vector space of $7 \times 7$ matrices, and $\mathrm{tr}: M \to \mathbb{F}$ is the trace map, how can you describe the subspace you are looking for? Could the rank-nullity theorem come in handy?

Answer (score 1):

$V=M_{7\times 7}=\{A_{7\times 7}=[a_{ij}]~|~\sum\limits_{i=1}^{7}a_{ii}=0, ~a_{ij}\in\mathbb{R}\}$ over the field $\mathbb{R}$.

dim($V$)$=49-1=48$, as $a_{11}=-\sum\limits_{i=2}^{7}a_{ii}$.

Observe that $\{E_{ij}, F_{ii}\}$ forms basis for $V$, where $E_{ij}$ is a matrix in which $1$ is placed at $(i,j)^{th}$ position, $i\neq j$ and rest all are zeros, and $F_{ii}$ is a matrix in which $-1$ is placed at $(1,1)$ position and $1$ is placed at $(i,i)$ position and rest all are zeros.

Comment: This is kind of an answer, but you really need your $F_{ii}$ to only range over $1 \leq i \leq 6$. How do you show that is a basis though? I think it comes back to the rank of the trace map...

Comment: I replaced $a_{11}$ by $-\sum\limits_{i=2}^{7}a_{ii}$..then $F_{ii}$ as defined above where $2\leq i\leq 7$.